# Flex AIR Android Video chat App with Camera LED enabled :: How to enable Camera LED enabled in AIR?

Tags: android, air, camera, streaming, led

I have developed a Flex Mobile project (Android) which is a Video chat and live streaming app.

Now I am facing an issue.

I need to enable Camera LED (flash) from my Application which is little tough because as such Flex does not interact with LED hardware of device.

So i wrote an ANE (Android Native Extension) and tried invoking Camera's LED and it worked in a Standalone mobile app.

But I used the same ANE in my video chat app with a button called flash.

Onclick of button should enable LED flash, it's not working as the Video Chat application is already using Camera and native extension which again tries to open another camera.

As we all know Android doesn't allow multiple access to Camera because of its singleton nature.

If i access my Video App my Flash doesn't work parallel.

So is there any way to pass my Native extensions camera object to flex mobile app and use the same for my chat app.

Native extension can only return primitive datatypes to flex is what my assumption.

Is there any alternate way or any solution which is feasible enough to access LED flash in my video chat application.

PS: I always use rear camera.

Thanks,
Veeru

Comment: Hi,Can anybody throw some light?